# Dynamic widths for css class with ::after pseudoelement

Tags: html, css

I'm doing some mvc testing and I've hit a roadblock when I'm going through my model to display some elements. Each element will have to have an "EXP" amount that is displayed dynamically in the `::after` element in the css.

- **Is there a way to dynamically change the width of the `::after` element?** I am passing through the width for each element through the model but I don't display it yet

[image: exp bar]

That's the bar that needs to change dynamically, here's an example piece of code of how I've done it so far:

```css
.pkmn-pc {
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .pkmn-summary, .pkmn-info {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .pkmn-summary {
        width: 193px;
        background: #745fb5;
        background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

        .pkmn-summary:after {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            left: -181px;
            bottom: -31px;
            height: 5px;
            background: green;
            width: 73%;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
        }

    .pkmn-info {
        background: #333538;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
    }

    .pkmn-outer {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    .pkmn-inner {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 3px;
    }

    .pkmn-sprite {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .pkmn-name {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .pkmn-lvl {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        display: block;
    }

    .crown {
        padding-top: 5px;
    }

    code {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: white;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pkmn-pc">
    <div class="pkmn-summary">
        <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
        <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
    </div>
    <div class="pkmn-info">
        <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
        <div class="pkmn-outer">
            <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
            <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
            <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
        </div>
        <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you have the info (level of EXP) available in the model, could you use that as an inline style on an element. Something like `<div class=".pkmn-exp" style="width: 73%;"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the EXP value available in the data (along with the other user info), you could create an element (we'll call it `.pkmn-exp`) and set the experience level (or width) in an inline style.

For example, if the user has an experience level of 73/100:

```
<div class="pkmn-exp" style="width:73%;"></div>
```

where the `73` comes from the user's data.

```css
.pkmn-pc {
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pkmn-summary,
.pkmn-info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.pkmn-summary {
  position: relative;
  width: 193px;
  background: #745fb5;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.pkmn-exp {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.pkmn-info {
  background: #333538;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
}

.pkmn-outer {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.pkmn-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3px;
}

.pkmn-sprite {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.pkmn-name {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.pkmn-lvl {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: block;
}

.crown {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

code {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pkmn-pc">
  <div class="pkmn-summary">
    <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
    <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
    <div class="pkmn-exp" style="width:73%"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-info">
    <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
    <div class="pkmn-outer">
      <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
      <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
      <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
    </div>
    <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the easiest solution to implement!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot script the ::after elements as they are not part of the dom.
You could either

- Use a set of predefined classes and apply them to parent
- add a bar element and script it like

```js
var p = 0;
var bar = document.querySelector(".pkmn-bar");
window.setInterval(function() {
  bar.style.width=p+"%";
  p++;
  if(p>100) p=0;
},50);
```

```css
.pkmn-pc {
        color: white;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .pkmn-summary, .pkmn-info {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .pkmn-summary {
        width: 193px;
        background: #745fb5;
        background: linear-gradient(15deg, #745fb5, #9a6dbb);
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
        white-space: nowrap;
        border-bottom: solid 5px grey;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .pkmn-bar {
        content: '';
        background: #745fb5;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: -5px;
        height: 5px;
        background: green;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    }

    .pkmn-info {
        background: #333538;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(102, 119, 136, 0.55);
    }

    .pkmn-outer {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    .pkmn-inner {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 3px;
    }

    .pkmn-sprite {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .pkmn-name {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .pkmn-lvl {
        font-size: 0.8em;
        display: block;
    }

    .crown {
        padding-top: 5px;
    }

    code {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 1em;
        color: white;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pkmn-pc">
    <div class="pkmn-summary">
        <img class="pkmn-sprite" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/e/ea/113MS.png" />
        <code class="pkmn-name">15Characterssss</code>
        <div class="pkmn-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pkmn-info">
        <img class="crown" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/c/c5/Leaf_Crown_Sprite.png" />
        <div class="pkmn-outer">
            <img class="heart" src="https://image.ibb.co/kB8vi6/heart.png">
            <div class="pkmn-inner"></div>
            <img class="star" src="https://image.ibb.co/e7w4bR/Shiny_VIStar.png">
        </div>
        <code class="pkmn-lvl">lvl 100</code>
    </div>
    
</div>
```